# Get value from basetype of validation context in custom validator

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am trying to write my own validation attribute but I am having trouble getting the value of a property from the inherited class.  This is my code:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
{
    if (context.ObjectType.BaseType == typeof(AddressModel))
    {
        PropertyInfo property = context.ObjectType.BaseType.GetProperty(_propertyName);

        // this is the line i'm having trouble with:
        bool isRequired = (bool)property.GetValue(context.ObjectType.BaseType); 

        return base.IsValid(value, context);
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

I don't know what I'm meant to pass into the `GetValue` as it is expecting an object but everything I pass in gives me a **property type does not match target** exception

I'm having to go to the base type as I am trying to get the value of a property from an inherited class and `context.ObjectInstance` doesn't include the necessary properties

Comment: I don't know how the validation framework works so I can't help with that, but `GetProperty` is expecting the instance of the object whose property you are calling.

Comment: @Vache is there any way to get that as `context.ObjectInstance` returns the current object but without any of the inherited properties from the base model class

Comment: `context.ObjectInstace` is simply an `Object`, can't you cast it to `AddressModel` (or whatever type you're working with) and use the object itself? As I said, I've never used that framework but I would try that...

Comment: Why doesn't `context.ObjectInstance` have access to the properties of the object it is inheriting from? Are they private? If so, you won't be able to get their values as those properties simply aren't available to your materialized derived object.

Comment: @ChrisHardie They are public but they just don't seem to be there, when I step through the code, the object instance only has the properties that are defined in the model - this is what I found really stupid about this whole thing.  Why doesn't the object instance have all the properties including the inherited ones

Comment: @Vache, have just tried casting it as the base model and it works - even though the object instance doesn't show any of the properties needed, when it gets cast they all show up!  If you would like to answer the question I'll give you the bounty.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pete I answered and I tried to give you some details. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply cast your object as the `AddressModel` and use it like that.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
{
    var addressModel = context.ObjectInstance as AddressModel
    if (addressModel != null)
    {
        // Access addressModel.PROPERTY here

        return base.IsValid(value, context);
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

`context.ObjectInstance` is of `object` type instead of your model's type because the validation framework wasn't created to explicitly validate your model, but it is the right object instance. Once it's casted you can use it normally.

As a side note, the reason why you were getting an error with `property.GetValue(context.ObjectType.BaseType)` is because the `GetValue` method expects the instance of the object whose property you are calling.

Comment: I have to wait a day to award bounty, will do when it lets me.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Pete and Vache I was trying to cast the ObjectInstance to the ObjectType (instead of being restricted to a specific model [AddressModel in this Question/Answer]) - both being members of ValidationContext. Any ideas on why  it won't let me? Does my question make sense? I can start a fresh post if needed. Thanks!

Comment: @srinivas.naik `ObjectType` is a variable representing a type, not a real type that you can cast to. For more information start a new question and show us your code

Comment: I don't know if I am right or not, but your will work for `AddressModel`. What if I am using the same validation in a different model i.e. `PersonModel`. What then?

Comment: @barnes If the property you are validating on `PersonModel` and `AddressModel` is the same maybe try to put an interface or a base class between them. Otherwise you might have to make two different validations. Tough to say without seeing the complete scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to cast `ObjectInstance` to its base type, so can you try this:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
{
    if (context.ObjectType.BaseType == typeof(AddressModel))
    {
        AddressModel model = (AddressModel)context.ObjectInstance;
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(AddressModel).GetProperty(_propertyName);

        bool isRequired = (bool)property.GetValue(model, null); 

        //OR YOU CAN INTERROGATE THE MODEL DIRECTLY
        var x = model.SomeProperty == true;

        return base.IsValid(value, context);
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should soft cast to the desired object type and save yourself the reflection, which is unnecessary when you know your desired type at compile-time.

This code assumes you'd place your custom attribute on the class definition of your model (versus on the individual properties). `value` will be the instance of the property or class you place the attribute on:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
{
    var addressModel = value as AddressModel;
    if (addressModel != null)
    {
        // Do some stuff against addressModel here to determine if valid...

        return base.IsValid(value, context);
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried working with the value as I thought it would be the object (as I had a look at alot of other people's posts that use the value) but for some reason in my case it was always null

Comment: @Pete what does the debugger say that the `value` object is?

Comment: nothing - it just says it's null and then if I try do a typeof on it it says it's not valid in this scope

Comment: @Pete show us some code where you use your custom attribute.

Comment: I'm just marking properties in my model with it: 
        [AddressRequired(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your postcode")]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }

Comment: Yes, but where is the `IsValid` code there called? What class or object is that in?

Comment: I think that it is part of MVCs builtin functionality and just gets called when I post my form back to the controller that is expecting that model.  It gets hit before my controller code gets hit anyway so I don't know what's calling it

Answer (score 0):

Issue:
I found that when accessing context.ObjectInstance only a couple of the properties were populated and the rest were null or default.
I checked in the related controller method and everything was being passed in with values to the view via the corresponding view model and mapped correctly from the data model to the view model.

Resolve:
When accessing the properties from the custom validation attribute via object instance, I had to include the desired property within the view for it to be correctly reflected and available - even if it was only @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.YourObject).